# How to split a string stream into different stream

Tags: java, stream, spliterator

I have a string stream like 5AA50100FF1837d437d437d40000

I want to split like if it contains 0100FF18 then 37d4 37d4 37d4 0000
How to do this

I need to split the stream and do the computation for that splited stream

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected ending `37d4 37d4 37d4 0000`?

Comment: It's a split based on index

Comment: What's a "string stream"? What role do streams play here?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this. Once the target is found, use the `index + target.length()` to find the start of the desired string.  Then, using find, find each grouping of four characters and stream the `MatchResults`, grabbing the matching group and return as an array. If no match of the target string, the array will be empty.

```
String target = "0100FF18";
String s = "5AA50100FF1837d437d437d40000";

String[] tokens = new String[0];
int index = 0;
if ((index = s.indexOf(target)) >= 0) {
    tokens = Pattern.compile("....")
            .matcher(s.substring(index + target.length())).results()
            .map(MatchResult::group).toArray(String[]::new);

}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

prints

```
[37d4, 37d4, 37d4, 0000]
```